# Remove local app M1 Mac that was created in Xcode

Tags: xcode, apple-m1

I'm working on an iOS Xcode project on an M1 Mac.  I set the run destination as (This Mac) and ran the app on the Mac. Now I need to delete the app to clear its data because I need to make sure a file copy operation happens on first run. A search in Finder shows me the app in /Users/my Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myXcodeProject-cpkgxnpaxvacnldboddpfgojwukv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos

I can delete the app from there but when I run it again all of its data is still there.
I don't see any other supporting files in that directory.
The data I want to delete are the files that are automatically copied to the Apps Documents Directory.   Any suggestions how to scrub that app off the Mac?

Comment: Is it in the Containers folder?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, open the terminal and do the following:

```
cd ~/Library/Containers
find . -iname "*bloons*"
```

This will return an output which is showing a match in an obscured directory name. You need to delete the app and its directory with:

```
rm -Rf 2EC6B4BC-DD8D-4D49-89A1-4376990BF693
```

The original answer could be found here:

https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/how-to-uninstall-ios-ipados-apps-on-m1-macs-and-where-do-they-store-their-files.2275923/?post=29453766#post-29453766

Comment: Also this is basically what I said already in a comment.